# How to iterate through rows and columns in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-science

I'm new to data science and I'm doing data scraping for a project, and I currently want to see which players will be free agents after the 2019-20 nba season.

I'm currently looping through a dataframe with players' salaries for the next few years, and I want to get the players' salaries for the 2019-20 nba season if the 2020-21 column is empty (this would mean they are a free agent) and their names as well, and then print it. If however, I get this error when I try to run my code.

How can I resolve this?

Data Frame:

[image]

[image]

```
Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

from nba_api.stats.static import players
player_dict = players.get_players()


url1 = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/contracts/players.html'
df1= pd.read_html(url1, header=0)


def free_agents(df1):
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        temp = df1.loc[i, "Player"], df1.loc[i, "2020-21"]
        for j in range(len(temp)):
            if temp[j][1] == 'nan':
                return df1.loc[i, "Player"], df1.loc[i, "2019-20"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, df1 is a list and not a dataframe. pandas.read_html returns a list of dataframes. Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Please try to print the contents of df1 and check the output.

Comment: Ok, so how do I convert it into one dataframe?

Comment: That would depend on the data. To test, try reading the data from the first element of the list. Something like: pd.read_html(url1, header=0)[0]. I would still advise to check the output to figure out the right strategy to handle reading the data.

Comment: See my edit above. I see what you mean by when it's a list of data frames, but how do I only get the values?

Comment: Can you share the output of 'pd.read_html(url1, header=0)' is a copy-pastable format. I can try check more on it.

Comment: You mean copy and paste the results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214027/discussion-between-anshul-and-dg123).

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `.read_html()` to pull in the table. This will return a list of tables and you want the table in index position 0. then you do a little data manipulation on the table using pandas to clean it a bit.

Once you have the table, you'll grab the row where columns `'2020-21'` is null, then get the `'Player'` column and print that:

```
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/contracts/players.html'
df1= pd.read_html(url1, header=0)[0]

# Use row at index 0 as the headers and drop that row
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0,:]
df1 = df1.iloc[1:,:].reset_index(drop=True)

# Get rows where 2020-21 is null, and get 'Player' column
players = df1[df1['2020-21'].isnull()]['Player']
print (players)
```

**Output:**

```
19               Paul Millsap
38           Hassan Whiteside
46                 Marc Gasol
48           Chandler Parsons
51                Serge Ibaka
52           Danilo Gallinari
58              Kent Bazemore
59              Tyler Johnson
60               Goran Dragić
61                Jeff Teague
62                Evan Turner
66           Tristan Thompson
71               Allen Crabbe
72             Derrick Favors
73             Reggie Jackson
77            Bismack Biyombo
82             Brandon Knight
88                Ian Mahinmi
90            Marvin Williams
92              Marcus Morris
96              Mason Plumlee
99            Jordan Clarkson
101              Solomon Hill
103    Michael Kidd-Gilchrist
106              Courtney Lee
112             Miles Plumlee
122          Maurice Harkless
125            Meyers Leonard
127            Andre Roberson
140               John Henson

563          Anthony Tolliver
564               Joakim Noah
566        Johnathan Williams
567                Tyler Cook
568                Donta Hall
569               Yante Maten
572              Jaylen Adams
573           Justin Anderson
575              Jeremy Pargo
576            Chasson Randle
577              Jonah Bolden
578              Josh Magette
579             Jarrod Uthoff
580             Dusty Hannahs
581            Derrick Walton
582               J.P. Macura
583               Sheldon Mac
584             Mychal Mulder
585                 Eric Mika
586              Zach Norvell
587              Malik Newman
588            Marques Bolden
589       Sir'Dominic Pointer
590               Paul Watson
591                Tyler Cook
594            William Howard
595             Isaiah Taylor
596               Tyler Lydon
597           Hollis Thompson
598                Tyler Ulis
Name: Player, Length: 202, dtype: object
```